# Creating a pytest fixture for window mocking in Kivy

Tags: python, mocking, kivy, pytest, fixtures

I'm trying to create some unit tests for my kivy classes to run on a CI/CD server. The problem is the CI/CD server doesn't have any display/window managers installed (ie X11) so the tests get "Unable to find any valuable Window provider" errors. I'm trying to create a pytest fixture to mock the window checking function, but it doesn't work. I've also tried adding `os.environ["KIVY_GL_BACKEND"] = "mock"` to the beginning of the file but it didn't help. Does anyone have any experience with this?

My code is as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture
def window_mock() -> Generator[Dict[str, Any], None, None]:
    """Mock window checking"""
    w_mock = Mock(spec=kivy.base.EventLoopBase)
    w_mock.ensure_window = Mock(wraps=lambda x, _: x())
    with patch('<my_custom_module>.kivy.base.EventLoopBase', new=w_mock):
        yield w_mock
```

I found this related discussion: https://gist.github.com/dustinfarris/8851078 but it doesn't work for my case.

This is the error that I get:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py:274: in __init__
    super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py:65: in __init__
    super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py:76: in __init__
    super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py:334: in __init__
    EventLoop.ensure_window()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
self = <kivy.base.EventLoopBase object at 0x7f154ef98950>
    def ensure_window(self):
        '''Ensure that we have a window.
        '''
        import kivy.core.window  # NOQA
        if not self.window:
            Logger.critical('App: Unable to get a Window, abort.')
>           sys.exit(1)
E           SystemExit: 1
.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py:128: SystemExit
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean here?

Comment: I mean implementing that solution had no effect on avoiding the errors. Also it is using a different methodology of setup/teardown instead of more modern fixtures.

Comment: I mean, what goes wrong? What errors do you get?

Comment: Also, I think Kivy might have some of its own mocks for running without opengl, maybe you can use those

Comment: As in, mocking out opengl so the rest of kivy runs as normal, not just mocking out the Window calls

Comment: I tried adding os.environ["KIVY_GL_BACKEND"] = "mock" to the beginning of the file but it didn't help. I've updated the original post with the error.